# Laravel Eloquent: How search array of objects column of type JSON

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a database column field that contains an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "label": "0-1",
    "key": 1
  },
  {
    "label": "1-3",
    "key": 2
  },
  {
    "label": "3-7",
    "key": 3
  }
]
```

How can I query by the label? To return if the matching label exists?

> **Update**: this worked for me:

```
Model::whereJsonContains('column', ['label' => '0-1']);
```

Comment: by `field` you mean an attribute on your `Model` or an input from a `Request` ?

Comment: I mean a column in a table of database

Comment: So that column must be saved as `JSON` ? I mean its datatype is `JSON` on the table schema.

Comment: It is cast as array in the database model but it is text.

Comment: And you want to apply the filter before or after getting the values in that field ?

Comment: I have "0-1" in the request. I want to know if any column contains "0-1"

Comment: Yes i get your intentions here but you still didn't answer whether you should apply the filtering before (which means to the `SQL` query that will fetch the models) or after getting the models from the Database ?

Comment: Before getting the models from the Database. before ->get();

Comment: ok then, does that field has the `JSON` datatype on the `DB` ?

Comment: No. It is not JSON. A text field that has been cast as an array.

Comment: If you don't set that field datatype as `JSON` i dont think it is possible to have `where` clauses against that field's content. The `JSON` datatype should be available since `MySQL 5.7`.

Comment: So please assume it is JSON field. How then?

Comment: as a start, you may consult [`MySQL` Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) about `JSON` searches.

Comment: Is it gonna be something like:

Model::where('column', function($item) use $request {
    $item->where('label', $request->label)
});

Comment: No, you should use `JSON` accessors/functions from the docs that i've already linked above. And depending on the `Laravel` version that you have, you might have support for `JSON` manipulation in `Eloquent` out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `whereJsonContains` in documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#json-where-clauses

```
$data = DB::table('table')
         ->whereJsonContains('column->label', '0-1')
         ->get();
```

Comment: It must iterate inside the "column".The column is an array of objects.